# Expandable menu items with CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is a new style of implemention menues which I see around stylish web sites: an expandable menu items. You can see a demo at [g4interactive.com](http://g4interactive.com/)

A stable menu looks like a vertical list of images:

[image: stable menu]

When you mouse over any of them, the menu item is extended via CSS3 tricks to:

[image: css3 expansion]

Can you point me to a tutorial, where similar effect is explained? If not, a 2-3 sentence "roadmap" of how to implement it would be sufficient. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to mock something up on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/4WXUu/) very quickly that should get you started. With CSS transitions, you can certainly animate the elements to show and hide well. This is the CSS I used:

```
a span {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: width 1s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in;
}
a img {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
a:hover span {
    width: 75px;
}
```

And the HTML for the navigation was:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" /><span>Link 1 text</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" /><span>Link 2 text</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" /><span>Link 3 text</span></a></li>
</ul>​
```

To take it further and get the angles you require, you would need to take a look at CSS's transform property that allows you to rotate elements too.

Hope that's enough to get you started!

Comment: To make it diagonal just try -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
Don't forget about browsers that are not webkit (like firefox).

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS3 transforms [and transitions, if you like] for this.

Does something like this help? http://jsfiddle.net/hvQhM/1/

1. Position the elements.
2. Add CSS3 transforms to each item.
3. Add CSS3 transforms on hover condition.
4. Add CSS3 transitions.

(I've only tested it in Chrome and those transforms can be picky, just a heads up.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/pmETG/

So far it works on Webkit and Firefox via CSS3 `transitions` and `transforms` (I used only `-webkit-` and `-moz-` prefixes) so add as many prefixes you need

Html

```
<ul>
    <li>1 <a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li>2 <a href="#">item 2</a></li>
    <li>3 <a href="#">item 3</a></li>
    <li>4 <a href="#">item 4</a></li>
    <li>5 <a href="#">item 5</a></li>
    <li>6 <a href="#">item 6</a></li>
    <li>7 <a href="#">item 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

Css

```
ul { 
    margin      : 80px 0 0 0; 
    padding     : 0; 
    white-space : nowrap;
}

li a { 
    padding-left: 10px; 
}

li {
    display     : block;
    padding     : 2px 10px 2px 40px;
    margin      : 0 0 15px 0;
    background  : #666;
    width       : 0;
    overflow    : hidden;
    cursor      : pointer;

    -webkit-transform        : rotate(-45deg) translateX(-22px);
    -webkit-transform-origin : 0 0;
    -webkit-transition       : all 0.33s linear 0s;

    -moz-transform           : rotate(-45deg) translateX(-22px);
    -moz-transform-origin    : 0 0;
    -moz-transition          : all 0.33s linear 0s;
}


li:hover {  
    background : #fff; 
    width      : 180px;
}
```

of course where I have placed simple numbers you will place icon images instead. Just adjust and tune as you want `translateX` offset.

Hope this helps to get the idea